# Unexpected discrepancy between two different predictions using linear regression

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I'm using `ggplot2` to plot some time-series data along with a linear regression line.  I'm interested to determine when the regression line will hit 82%.  Visual inspection of the graph suggests that this will happen around November 15, 2017.  But when I use R's `predict.lm()` function, I get a different answer: Aug. 12, 2017.  Shouldn't these two methods give me the same answer?  Ultimately, I'd like to annotate the graph with a text label that shows the intercept date.

```
require(ggplot2)
temp <- "End.Date    Save.Rate
1       2015-05-31     0.67
2       2015-07-31     0.67
3       2015-09-30     0.69
4       2015-11-30     0.71
5       2016-01-30     0.70
6       2016-03-31     0.72"

df <- read.table(text = temp, header = TRUE)
df$End.Date <- as.POSIXct(df$End.Date, origin="1970-01-01", tzone="America/New_York")

save.rate.lm = lm(End.Date ~ Save.Rate, data=df)
newdata <- data.frame(Save.Rate = 0.82)
temp <- predict.lm(save.rate.lm, newdata)
predicted.date <- as.POSIXct(as.data.frame(temp)[1,], origin="1970-01-01",
                             tzone="America/New_York")
print(predicted.date)

x.lims <- c(as.POSIXct(NA), as.POSIXct("2017-12-31", origin="1970-01-01",
                                       tzone="America/New_York"))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=End.Date, y=Save.Rate)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method='lm', fill=NA, fullrange=TRUE) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -45, hjust = 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks('month'), labels = date_format('%b-%Y'),
                   limits=x.lims) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.82)
print(p)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just invert a linear regression (i.e. `date ~ 1+rate` vs `rate ~ 1 +date`) and expect to get the same answer (e.g., see [this question on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20553/effect-of-switching-response-and-explanatory-variable-in-simple-linear-regression)).  As far as I know there is no simple way to use `predict.lm` on the inverse-regression to get the answer you are looking for. You need to fit rate as a function of date and use some algebra to get the predicted date. Below I show a simple calculation that works for your specific question; the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076242/how-to-predict-x-values-from-lm) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191857/inverse-of-predict-function-in-r) give you some additional canned solutions ...

```
fit2 = lm(Save.Rate ~ End.Date, data=df)
## y = a + bx
## x* = (y-a)/b
cc <- coef(fit2)
pred.date <- as.POSIXct((0.82-cc[1])/cc[2],origin="1970-01-01",
                             tzone="America/New_York")
##               (Intercept) 
## "2017-11-19 17:26:28 EST"
```

The picture:

```
p+geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(pred.date),lty=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm curious if there is a way to accomplish the same (correct) result using `predict.lm()`, like I tried to do in my original code example.

Comment: @AlexC. : don't think so.

Comment: Inverse prediction is a common task in analytical chemistry. Thus, there is `chemCal::inverse.predict`. It is not vectorized and doesn't preserve attributes (such as a datetime class), but it calculates standard error and confidence interval.

Answer (score 2):

Ben Bolker explains why your approach doesn't work.

However, you can just flip the axes in ggplot2 with `coord_flip` and use a regression with error terms in x-direction (instead of the usual y-direction):

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(y=End.Date, x=Save.Rate)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method='lm', fill=NA, fullrange=TRUE) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -45, hjust = 0)) +
  scale_y_datetime(breaks = date_breaks('month'), labels = date_format('%b-%Y'),
                   limits=x.lims) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0.82) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = as.numeric(predicted.date)) + #to illustrate it works
  coord_flip()
print(p)
```

However, this is not recommended since the uncertainty of your time values is most likely much smaller than the uncertainty of your `Save.Rate` values. Thus, you should probably do the regression `Save.Rate ~ End.Date` as in your plot and do inverse prediction as shown in Ben's answer.